# How to determine if union case property was named by compiler

Tags: .net, f#

F# lets you optionally name union case properties.
If you don't, the compiler will automatically pick a name for you during compilation (Item1...n).

```
type Foo =
| Nothing
| AutomaticallyNamed of string
| Named of nameOfProperty: string
```

The only thing I could come up with was a simple string compare on the name on whatever [GetFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/unioncaseinfo.getfields-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) returns.

```
let testCase = Named "bar"
let caseInfo, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(testCase, typeof<Foo>)

caseInfo.GetFields()
```

Is there a more reliable way to determine if a name was generated by the compiler?

Comment: I'm quite surprised those names are not erased during compilation. `Item1..n` are just standard `System.Tuple` element names.

Comment: That's a possibility I didn't think of, but I'm glad the names stick around somewhere. But yeah, Item1..n are the standard System.Tuple names. If you only have one unnamed property, it names the property simply "Item". My .net IL foo is not strong enough, but I made a quick sample with LinqPad: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7326aaf57e3f6e2bd30ade12618ff859

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite interesting question. It turns out that the case fields are not in fact stored as a `System.Tuple`, but are compiled into standard .NET properties with a backing field on the nested class representing the union case.

If you look at the generated code in ILSpy or similar disassembler, you'll find a few curious bits and pieces:

1. There's nothing on the property to tell you that it has a user-provided name, so if you're looking for a nice and clean solution here, you're out of luck.
2. However, when a field has a user-provided name, the backing field (not the property) will be generated with the underscore in front of the name (i.e. `_nameOfProperty`). So you can drill down to it using reflection if you call `GetMembers` on the union case nested class, providing `NonPublic ||| Instance` binding flags.
3. Alternatively, the same names are used for constructor arguments to the single non-public constructor of the union case class, so you can get the same information by inspecting the parameters of the constructor - `GetConstructors` again with non-public binding flags, then `GetParameters`.
4. Things are never this simple though - there's one caveat here in that if you actually name your field using the naming scheme the compiler uses - i.e. `Item42` - it will get compiled without underscore, as if it was assigned by the compiler. Though luckily compiler is smart enough to skip the ordinal you've already used.

So you could in theory detect if the name is user-provided or not, but it's cumbersome, circumstancial and depends on internal implementation details that are not guaranteed to stay as they are.

Comment: I was hoping someone else would come to a different conclusion. I noticed the underscore in the backing field as well. But it seems like this doesn't offer any more certainty than checking the property name. So I think I'm going to go with what I already have. Seeing as it's only me who's going to use that code, I should be fine. On a different note, if I'm reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/tuples#compiled-form-of-tuples correctly, it compiles to a System.Tuple if targeting .net < 4.

Comment: @Brunner: That doc is just about how there was no `System.Tuple` in BCL before .NET 4.0 and F# used a local copy of that type that lived in `FSharp.Core`. It has nothing to do with how DUs were compiled.

Comment: welp, you are right - should have reread the topic's title again.